# Scikit learn import error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I installed scikit-learn without any issues but when I try to import the module I received the following error:

> TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling using both `pip` and the downloadable `whl` file.  I have `numpy`+`mkl` and `scipy` installed.

Comment: Could show us your actual code please? The relevant part.

Comment: I'm testing in the command prompt.  I type "import sklearn as sk". That's all.  The module appears in the list when I type help("modules")

Comment: And typing `import sklearn as sk` is literally the only thing you did inside python interactive shell?

Comment: yes that's all.  I tried importing numpy and scipy before importing scikit but it didn't make a difference

Comment: Does this also happen with a classic python script? Working from a file instead of from the interactive shell?

Comment: I just tried it and yes it gets the same error

Comment: I'm sorry, but without looking at your setup and/or without more informations it seems difficult to answer you.

Comment: here's more of the error, if it helps.  I can't fit the whole thing:  File "C:\Users\michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\
site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\
site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 406, in <module>
    if np_version < (1, 12, 0):
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Comment: okay, thanks for the help

Comment: As a last resort, I would advise you to use something like anaconda (see link at the end) to manage your modules when it comes to doing sciency stuff in python :-)

https://www.continuum.io/

Comment: I solved my issue by uninstalling version 0.18.1 and installing version 0.18     Don't know why that fixes it but I got it working

Comment: I have encountered the same problem just now. Where did you download version 0.18.0 ? All I see available is 0.18.1.

Comment: Nevermind. This worked for me: `pip install scikit_learn==0.18.0`

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue by uninstalling version 0.18.1 and installing version 0.18

Don't know why that fixes it but I got it working